# JQuery.Next() with not selector not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to setup a rotating panel, however I have three states: active, inactive, disabled.

I only want to rotate between active and inactive panels and skip over disabled panels. If there is no more inactive panels rotate back to the first panel.

However with the code below you click the button it will select panel1, then panel 2, and back to panel 1, not selecting panel5.. If I remove the not selector from bold part below it works as expected. I think it's my understanding (or lack thereof) of the next operator. Any thoughts?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#rotate").click(function () {
            var ActivePanel = $('.active');                 //Get the current active panel 
            var NextPanel = $('.active').next('.inactive:not(.disabled)'); //Get the next panel to be active. 
            if (NextPanel.length == 0) NextPanel = $("#panel1"); //check for null next. if so, rotate back to the first panel

            console.log("Active Panel: ", ActivePanel);
            console.log("Next Panel: ", NextPanel);

            $(ActivePanel).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
            $(NextPanel).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active"); 
        });
    });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="rotate">Rotate Active Panel</button>
    <div id="panel1" class="active"><p>Some Content</p></div>
<div id="panel2" class="inactive"></div>
<div id="panel3" class="inactive disabled"></div>
<div id="panel4" class="inactive disabled"></div>
<div id="panel5" class="inactive"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the next siblings `~` selector followed by a nested `.class`, `:not(.class)` and `:first` selector

```
$("#rotate").click(function() {
    var ActivePanel = $('.active');
    var NextPanel = $(".active ~ .inactive:not(.disabled):first");
    if (NextPanel.length == 0) NextPanel = $("#panel1");    
    $(ActivePanel).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
    $(NextPanel).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
});
```

---

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/vfVBB/

---

**[Next Siblings Selector (“prev ~ siblings”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)**

> ***Description**: Selects all sibling elements that follow after the "prev" element, have the same parent, and match the filtering "siblings" selector.*

Comment: This works but I don't understand why this doesn't work:  var NextPanel = $(".active").siblings(".inactive:not(.disabled):first");

Comment: `.siblings()` takes all of that elements siblings, before or after. This is why the 1st elements selects the 2nd element and the 2nd element selects the 1st.

Comment: Yes I see now. Thanks for teaching me the '~' selector. 10 points for gryffindor. For those interested the documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Comment: So this is similar to nextAll in nature.

Answer (score 6):

The `next` method only returns the immediate sibling if it matches the selector. Use [the `nextAll` method.](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Try the following:

```
$("#rotate").click(function() {
  var activePanel = $('.active'); //Get the current active panel 
  var nextPanel = activePanel.nextAll('.inactive').not('.disabled').first(); //Get the next panel to be active. 
  if (!nextPanel.length) {
    nextPanel = $("#panel1"); //check for null next. if so, rotate back to the first panel
  }

  console.log("Active Panel: ", activePanel);
  console.log("Next Panel: ", nextPanel);

  $(activePanel).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
  $(nextPanel).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
});
```

[See here for jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tgmeD/)

Comment: This just rotates between panel1 and panel2.

Comment: @rich.okelly: your answer helped me a LOT! Thanks for posting... it gave me an idea on how I should approach my current scenario (Wizard with next/previous buttons). I needed to rotate to the next not answered question! AWESOME. It's working now... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it

```
.nextAll(".inactive:not(.disabled):first")
```